# Logging just the SQL with Sequelize logging, for audit logging?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is it possible to get just the SQL when doing logging in Sequelize? I am wanting to log all the modifying SQL statements, as part of an audit process, but the call to my logging function receives text of the form:

```
 Executing (9dcde3e9-cd1c-4964-bf87-a29d75a8c76e): INSERT INTO `login_attempts` VALUES (1,'bob@example.com',1,'2016-11-30 18:20:26.540 +00:00');
```

In my Node.JS I can do something such as, though I wondering whether it is possible to have something simpler, since it will be called on every operation to the database:

```
if (operation.startsWith('Executing') && operation.indexOf(':') > -1) {
   var str = operation.substring(operation.indexOf(':') + 2, operation.length);
   if (str.startsWith('INSERT') || str.startsWith('DELETE') || str.startsWith('UPDATE')) {
       logFile.write(str);
   }
}
```

My need is for auditing, so if this is the wrong approach for creating an audit log, I would be interested in alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression seems lot simpler to me. 
For your case

`logFile.write(operation.replace(/Executing \([^\)]*\):\s*/, ''));`